# Spring boot MVC application JSPs not rendering in jboss-eap-6.4

Tags: spring, jboss

I have a Spring boot MVC application deployed in `jboss-eap-6.4`.But JSP page with spring form tags not rendering.

I have added below lines in application.properties file

```
server.servlet-path=/*
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Able to hit the controller using url pattern but getting below error when I try to redirect jsp from controller.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
(http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Cannot forward to error page for request [/login]
as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may
have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere
Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Please let me know if `jboss-eap-6.4` support Spring boot MVC application with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem. After installing the Jboss patch jboss-eap-6.4.6-patch.zip the problem does not occur anymore.

After patching I did not need to use the setting server.servlet-path=/*